# Local variables default to strong or weak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Lets say I have local variable(not property) Obj *x = d, is d's reference count incremented? Or is it default a weak reference?

Answer (score 6):

Apple's documentation (`Variable Qualifiers` section) said:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

> *__strong* is the default. An object remains “alive” as long as there is a strong pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Say you write

```
__weak NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

What happens? What happens is that the only reference to that array is in a weak variable, which means it gets deallocated immediately and myArray is set to nil. Now say you write

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

What would happen if the default is "weak"? Does that answer your question?

Comment: you didn't actually answer the question. you give him riddle. Local variables are Strong by default.

Answer (score 1):

They are strong by default.

[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30)